How the email client (Outlook) determines what is inside or outside
After successful completion of the autodiscover process, the email client (Outlook) receives Autodiscover.xml from the Exchange Server (2016 in my case). How does it decide whether to use InternalUrl or ExternalUrl?
This is determined by its own IP (white or gray) or something else?
Tnx.

If the Active Directory servers can be reached then the information from there is prioritized and hence the internalUrl wins. But there are other factors that have influence like the cached configuration (Last Known Good (LKG) configuration).
This article explains how it exactly works with Outlook 2016. And this is the official documentation from Microsoft about Autodiscover.

Thanks for the links to the articles, but they describe how Outlook obtains the Autodiscover XML file, but do not describe the next step - how does Outlook select InternalUrl or ExternalUrl?

Outlook determines whether to use the InternalUrl or ExternalUrl based on the network location relative to the Exchange server. This decision is primarily made by checking the network connectivity and determining whether the client is inside or outside the corporate network.
In essence, Outlook uses the network topology and accessibility of specific services to decide which URL to use. The IP address itself (white or gray IP) isn't the primary factor; rather, it's the ability to connect to certain internal resources that guides this decision.

Most likely this is true, but I’m interested in how exactly this happens.
In my case, the client connects to the VPN, ends up in the DMZ (10.0.0.0/22) from where only DNS (53 tcp/udp) and the Exchange server (443 tcp) are available. And the client tries to connect only to the InternalUrl, but it needs to connect to the ExternalUrl.

When the client connects to the VPN, it gets an IP address in the DMZ range (10.0.0.0/22). DMZs are often used to isolate and protect internal networks from external access, allowing only specific traffic to pass through.
In your case, the DMZ only allows DNS (port 53) and HTTPS (port 443) traffic to the Exchange server. This means that the client can resolve the domain name and connect to the Exchange server over HTTPS.
The client is configured to connect to the Exchange server using the InternalUrl, which is most likely an internal address that is not accessible from the DMZ. However, it needs to use the ExternalUrl, which is accessible from the DMZ.
